# Firefox element.event works but element.addEventlistener does not

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, dom-events, event-listener

I am having some problems with `addEventListener` in Firefox.
I have an iframe on my site for a WYSIWYG area I built myself.

I want the iframe to look more like a normal textarea so I want a border around the iframe on focus. First tp (textpreview) is found like this (and works well):

```
var tp = document.getElementById('iframe-textpreview');
var iframe = tp;    

if(tp.contentDocument){ // normal
    tp = tp.contentDocument;
}
else if(tp.contentWindow){ // old IE
    tp = tp.contentWindow.document; 
}
//Open and close for Firefox
tp.open();
tp.close();
tp.designMode = 'on';
```

Then I try to attach an `eventlistener` and log when the event fires. This works in Chrome, Opera and the most recent IE but not in Firefox:

```
//Doesn't work in Firefox
tp.body.addEventListener('focus', function(){ console.log('focus...')});
tp.body.addEventListener('blur', function(){ console.log('blur...')});
```

This does work however:

```
//Firefox
tp.body.onfocus = function(){ console.log('focus...')};
tp.body.onblur = function(){ console.log('blur...')};
```

I have cleared the cache on Firefox and tried with another computer, still no luck to get the first option working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox doesn't fire the event handler on the body element for some reason, instead you have to attach the event handler to the iframe itself or an actual element inside the iframe.

Focusing on the iframe itself, and not the body, seems to work in all browsers

```
tp.addEventListener('focus', function(){ console.log('focus...')});
tp.addEventListener('blur', function(){ console.log('blur...')});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works in Firefox. It doesn't seem to work in webkit or IE now though, but I can use them both I guess.

Comment: Worked fine in Chrome here ?

Comment: Actually it doesn't work in chrome, that was another solution I tried that didn't work in Firefox, so I guess you have to use both ?

Comment: Yeah apparently. It is probably possible to attach an eventlistener to an child element of the iframe body but that complicates things more for me, I'll just use both solutions.
Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: @adeneo I would assume the "some reason" is that the body is not actually getting focus in this case, at least in Gecko.  `tp.document.activeElement` would tell for sure.